# Правильная привязка коллекции для ListBox в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть элемент `ListBox`

```
<ListBox Width="400"
         Margin="60,10,61,10"
         BorderThickness="0"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Height="102">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Соответствующий странице код C#

```
public partial class AllPurchases : Page
{
    private List<string> items = new List<string>();
    public List<string> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return items;
        }
    }
    public AllPurchases()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this; // для привязки данных
        items.Add("1");
        items.Add("2");
        items.Add("3");                
    }
}
```

Как видно из кода, я осуществляю привязку коллекции к `ListBox` посредством установки `this.DataContext = this;`. 
Есть 2 вопроса:

1. Как установить `this.DataContext = this;` не в коде, а в разметке XAML ?
2. Можно ли в XAML задать объекут не устранавливая `DataContext`? Как для этого изменить строку `ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В XAML, у Вашей `Page` можно написать следующее:

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

Это будет тоже самое, что Вы сделали в code behind.
Что касается 2-го вопроса: насколько я знаю, `DataContext` по умолчанию выставлен в `null`, а значит так или иначе его выставить придётся(либо через родителя, либо напрямую).

На а если по уму, то всё это делается через MVVM паттерн, следуя которому подобных вопросов возникать не будет.